# Append JSON values to a global array using Alamofire and SwiftyJson

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, alamofire, swifty-json

```
var imgURLArray = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    myTableView.delegate = self
    myTableView.dataSource = self

    Alamofire.request("https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/?access_token=####&count=10").responseJSON { (response) in
            if let value = response.result.value {
                let json = JSON(value)
                for i in 1...9 {
                    if let imageURL = json["data"][i]["images"]["standard_resolution"]["url"].string {
                        self.imgURLArray.append(imageURL)
                    } else {
                      print("no way")
                    }
                }
                print(self.imgURLArray)
            }
        }
    }
```

When I print `imgURLArray` it is empty.
I tried `dispatchQueue` and it's still not working.
I also tried passing it to tableview and reload, but it doesn't work either.

Comment: Without knowing the JSON it's rather impossible to answer the question.

Comment: there is an access token which is private .. the problem is not in json at all , i can print array inside the closure and it is working fine , the problem is the array is empty outside the closure

Comment: *When I print imgURLArray it is empty.* is pretty misleading as in the given code you are printing the array **inside** the closure. The request works asynchronously. Just do the things you need to do inside the closure.